# FOR loop in function exists before ending

Tags: python, function, for-loop, wordle-game

I know there are already countless clones of Wordle. Nevertheless I try to program my own version.
In the function is_real_word it should be checked whether the entered word of the user occurs in the word list. If so, the variable check = True.
However, the FOR loop is always exited when the counter is at 1.
The file "5_letter_words.txt" contains 3 entries: wetter, wolle, watte
And last but not least also the return value for eingabewort is sometimes NONE. And I don't know why?

```
import random


def word_list():
    wordle = []
    with open("5_letter_words.txt", "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            myTuple = line.strip()
            wordle.append(myTuple)
    return wordle


def random_word(wordlist):
    return random.choice(wordlist)


def is_real_word(guess, wordlist):

        for word in wordlist:
        if guess == word:
            return True
    return False


def check_guess(guess, randomword):
    randomword_tuple = []
    guess_tuple = []

    length = len(randomword)
    output = ["-"] * length

    for index in range(length):
        if guess[index] == randomword[index]:
            output[index] = "X"
            randomword = randomword.replace(guess[index], "-", 1)

    for index in range(length):
        if guess[index] in randomword and output[index] == "-":
            output[index] = "O"
            randomword = randomword.replace(guess[index], "-", 1)

    return ''.join(output)


def next_guess(wordlist):
    guess = input('Please enter a guess: ')
    guess = guess.lower()
    valid = is_real_word(guess, wordlist)
    if valid == False:
        print('Thats not a real word!')
        next_guess(wordlist)
    else:
        return guess


def play():
    target = []
    target = word_list()

    zufallswort = str()
    zufallswort = random_word(target)

    eingabewort = next_guess(target)
    print('Eingabewort: ', eingabewort)
    print('Zielwort: ', zufallswort)


play()
```

Comment: just style wise... `check = bool()` and `check = 1` would be better as `check = False` and `check = True` respectively.  And `counter = int()` is unnecessary - you do not have to initialise vars in python, and the immediate next line you set it to the value you actually wanted.

Comment: where you do `check = 1; break; return check` you could just directly `return True` from that line in the loop

Comment: `counter = len(wordlist); for i in range(0, counter - 1):` and `wordlist[i]` ... you can simplify this in python with just `for word in wordlist: if guess == word`

Comment: entire `is_real_word` function could just be `return guess in wordlist`

Comment: @Anentropic the point of style about `check = bool()` and `check = 1` was a messy fault. Thanks for notification.

Comment: I changed the code of `for i in range(0, counter - 1):...` to `for word in wordlist:...` ..it is working now. But I do not understand why. What's wrong with the for-loop?

Comment: `myTuple = line.strip()` ...`myTuple` here is just a string, so different var name would be better e.g.`word`

Comment: _"the return value for eingabewort is sometimes NONE"_ it's because sometimes you reach the end of the function without returning anything.  I think you want `return next_guess(wordlist)` in the `if valid == False:` block (and for better style you can write it as `if not valid:`)

Comment: these lines in `check_guess` do nothing and can be deleted `randomword_tuple = []` `guess_tuple = []`

Comment: it's because sometimes you reach the end of the function without returning anything. Sorry I don't understand. 
When program pointer is here `return guess` in function `next_guess(wordlist)` the string of value `guess` is the entered word by user.

Comment: `return guess` is in an `else:` clause currently... if the condition to go into the else clause is not met then execution will reach the bottom of the function and return `None`

Comment: Why not? If word is not valid enter a new one (`if not valid` clause). Else the return value is true return guess string (`else` clause).
Otherwise, if `return guess` is outside `if` clause. The `return guess` string is not correct also.

Comment: it does this: `if valid == False:` `print('Thats not a real word!')` `next_guess(wordlist)` and then it reaches the end of the else clause and looks for the next line in the function, but it's at the end of the function so it returns None

Comment: that is why you need to `return next_guess(wordlist)`

Comment: Alright, I got it. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if your function word_list returns the list?
You dont give a clear path, only the file name.

If it works, try:

```
def is_real_word(guess, wordlist):
    for word in wordlist:
        if guess == word:
            check = 1
            break
    return check
```